# Testing Android App GUI

Tags: android, user-interface

i am developing andriod app. On GUI development, I have issue how to test if GUI works on different Android phones (i mean with different screen size, density and etc). How i can check if everything is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking for the hardest thing to do in Android development :)

1. Read [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).
2. If you are targeting motorola devices, [here](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/tools/) are a bunch of SDK addons for the emulator.
3. If you need to test a specific device, you can try using [perfectomobile](http://www.perfectomobile.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Can't you test that with the [emulator](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html)?

You'll have to create multiple [AVDs](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/managing-avds.html) ("Android Virtual Devices") with the settings you want for Resolution, Density and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use two steps:

1. Create a few **emulators** with different screen-sizes and versions of Android.
2. After succesfully testing step 1 I hand out my app to some **friends** with different Android phones and let them test my app.

Answer (score 0):

You can test your android app. without using any mobile phone..
Just go through the link(if your app is using flash) [here](http://blogs.adobe.com/actionscriptdocs/2010/06/test_your_flash_platform_andro.html)..

Or See another [tool](http://www.smith-house.org/open.html)

Comment: You can download various skins available in [this](http://teavuihuang.com/android/). and test your Application